# Работа со звуком в приложениях Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

В проекте UWP при использовании `MediaElement`, когда сворачиваешь окно проигрывание трека останавливается. В сети пишут что нужно использовать `BackgroundMediaPlayer`, только хотелось бы объяснений как его использовать. Или есть какой-то другой способ решения этой проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вкратце: да, нужно использовать `BackgroundMediaPlayer` плюс имплементировать `IBackgroundTask`. Это входная точка для
работы приложения, когда оно свернуто. Позволит управлять произведением музыки в свернутом состоянии. У Microsoft есть [официальный пример](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio).

Comment: А вот пример  http://metanit.com/sharp/uwp/13.3.php